# Avoid parsing json subfield in Spark

Tags: json, apache-spark, schema

I have json files with a complex schema (see below) that I am reading using Spark. I found out that some of the fields are duplicated in the source data thus Spark throws an error during reading (as expected). The duplicate names are under the `storageidlist` field. What I would like to do is to load the `storageidlist` field as an unparsed string into a string type column and parse it manually afterwards. Would this be possible in Spark?

```
root
 |-- errorcode: string (nullable = true)
 |-- errormessage: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ip: string (nullable = true)
 |-- label: string (nullable = true)
 |-- status: string (nullable = true)
 |-- storageidlist: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- errorcode: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- errormessage: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- fedirectorList: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- directorId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- errorcode: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- errordesc: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- metrics: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- portMetricDataList: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- data: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- ts: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- errorcode: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- errordesc: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- metricid: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- portid: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- status: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- status: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- metrics: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- status: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- storageGroupList: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- storageid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- sublabel: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ts: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the options is to create a Java Class for this JSON object .
In that way, you can read the input JSON and spark won't throw an error during reading. Duplicates are allowed as far as the schema you have defined matches the input schema.

```
    spark.read()
            .schema(Encoders.bean(YourPOJO.class).schema())
            .option("encoding", "UTF-8")
            .option("mode", "FAILFAST")
            .json("data.json")
            .as(Encoders.bean(YourPOJO.class));

}
```